# Code-first migration: foreign key with default value of empty Guid

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Project details:

- ASP.NET 4.5
- MVC 5
- EF 6

I am doing a code-first project, and in my migration I am looking to set up default values for lots of things. One thing involves two very specific types of foreign keys to lookup tables. Since these lookup tables must *always* be loaded with a default value already selected, there is one value in these lookup tables that will always have a `Guid.Empty` value (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) as its primary key, so that it can be easily identified as the default value.

I am trying to find a way to have the foreign keys that make use of these two lookup tables to default to an empty Guid if they are passed a null value. *This is added insurance* just in case I miss a spot in the code itself where I am supposed to replace a null value with an empty Guid, but don’t. Plus, in this project in particular there will be scheduled weekly imports from an external database, and I want to be able to have all imported data have this default value in its foreign key without having to do extra work. Having the foreign key have this empty Guid as a default value would be very handy from several different angles.

And yes, I use Guids *as* Guids, not as varchar(128) strings. These foreign keys are non-nullable `uniqueidentifier` fields.

In terms of the migration script, I am now looking to manually add a default value to the field creation process, but I am at a loss as to how to manually insert an empty Guid as a default value into a `uniqueidentifier` field..

I have made a post [over at dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144582/) to handle the MS SQL Server 2008 portion of this question.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my other post [over at dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144582/), the indications are that the answer to adding a default `Guid.Empty` to the non-null `uniqueidentifier` field within a migration script is as such:

```
[foreign key] = c.Guid(nullable: false, defaultValue: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'));
```

I have yet to test this out, so if I am in error please comment on this post.